# Whats app (web.whatsapp.com/send) send not working

Tags: whatsapp, sendmessage, whatsapi

https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=
is redirecting to web but not opening the right mobilenumber with text message.
Anything changed ?

Comment: yes i same problem

Comment: There seems to be no update from whatsapp regarding same.

Answer (score 2):

Received From WhatsApp Support-We are aware of the issue and we are working on fixing it in a future update of WhatsApp. Unfortunately, we can't comment on any future release dates at this time.