# Send message on WhatsApp on Web using HTML or JavaScript

Tags: whatsapp

I want to send message through whatsapp web.

I am using following code but its not working:

```
https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext
```

I am unable to see contact list to send this encoded message.  I took reference from: [WhatsApp.comHow to use click to chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat)

Comment: Received From WhatsApp Support: We are aware of the issue and we are working on fixing it in a future update of WhatsApp. Unfortunately, we can't comment on any future release dates at this time See: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56377051/3473122) **EDIT:** Started working again

Comment: Hey hey, any luck with finding an answer?  Did what I post below help?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the domain from `wa.me` to `api.whatsapp.com`, like this...

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=text
```

Then you can have it send whatever text you'd like.  You also have the option to specify a phone number...

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=text&phone=1234
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `wa.me` currently only works when you specify *BOTH* a phone number *AND* a message, like so:

```
https://wa.me/12345?text=urlencodedtext
```

If you don't know the phone number, or don't like that parameter, please use the `api.whatsapp.com` format.

**October, 2020 Update:** `wa.me` was partially fixed.  However, unlike `api.whatsapp.com`, *it will not show an image preview of the site's `og:image` tags.*  So, keep using `api.whatsapp.com` as suggested above.