# Whatsapp share link not working from mobile

Tags: asp.net, url, mobile, share, whatsapp

I am using aspx to initialize the [**whatsApp click to chat feature**](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/26000030/) to share a link.
The aspx code is :

```
<a href='<%#"https://wa.me/?text="+ Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)%>' class="fa fa-whatsapp social-share-link a-fb-whatsapp" target="_blank"></a>
```

The link was working fine. I was able to share the link. But in the recent months i am not able to share the link as i get a message from whatsapp in my mobile displayed as

> Couldn't open link

Screen Shot:

[image]

***NOTE: I am able to share from web browser but not from my mobile.***

Is there anything wrong in the syntax or has whatsapp updated their feature, but i dont think so as their docs are still having the same info ?

***Edit: The output url looks like this in chrome inspector:***

https://wa.me/?text=https%3a%2f%2fwww.website.com%2fblog%2fPageName.aspx%3fblog%3dtitleword-your-titleword-system-using-titleword%26id%3d10%26temp%3dq

Comment: What happens if you use just 1 word as text instead of the url?

Comment: I tried that at first when i was trying to implement and it was working fine..

Comment: I just tried my own text and it worked, then I tried your link and it doesn't. So its something about the text you are passsing

Comment: ok.. Let me try again with some other text..

Comment: Not working Still.. But working fine in incognito mode..Strange problem..

Comment: But able to open in a new tab.. May be I thing target="_blank" is causing some problem

Comment: Great question, upvoted!  Hey, I know it's been 2 years, but anything thought on selecting an accepted answer?  Thanks, cheers!

Comment: @HoldOffHunger  The current accepted answer is what I have used in some sites and are still working.. I dont think.. the api.whatsapp.com is gonna work! never tried though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same link in different android browser(FireFox) and it was working fine.

For chrome i changed the link to this -> **whatsapp://send?text=**

My code:

```
string WhatsappShareURL = "whatsapp://send?text=" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
hlWhatsappMobile.NavigateUrl = Server.UrlEncode(WhatsappShareURL);
```

For Computers:
I use this link -> https://wa.me/?text=

My code:

```
string WhatsappShareURL = "https://wa.me/?text=" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
hlWhatsappWeb.NavigateUrl = Server.UrlEncode(WhatsappShareURL);
```

Then i toggle them in jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 520) {
            //Show mobile link
        }
        else {
            //Show Web link
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For computers, you will want to use this link...

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourTextHere
```

Otherwise, if you use `wa.me`, you will get an error page, unless you have the phone number included.  For example, this links to an error: https://wa.me/?text=SomeTexttoShare

Typically, you don't know the number, and you want the user to specify.  In that case, *you MUST* use the `api.whatsapp.com` domain.

Comment: The wa.me link was working fine till last week. has whatsapp updated it?

Comment: I thought it was working just fine a week ago, too!  But after researching a bit, I'm not really sure.  Maybe it's been broken a while?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56372575/2430549